# Is it possible to divide the address from saved search so that it is divided into three specific rows in Advanced PDF / HTML Templates?

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript, html-pdf, saved-searches

By making a column with the client's address and imposing an address from saved search to Advanced PDF / HTML Templates, I would like to know if I can somehow manipulate the code with this value, eg to create 3 different lines of code from it as it should look in the sample delivery address.

I've tried to reduce the size of the table to such an extent that the address itself jumps to the next line by default, but I would like to be able to manipulate it so that I can tell when it(the line of adress) can change the line. The problem with changing the size of the table can be such that at higher values something can go wrong.

Here is the example of table I'm working with:

```
<td style=" width: 100%;"><br />Buyer:
    <table style="width: 180px; font-weight: bold; display: table;"><tr>
        <td>${result.billaddress}</td>
    </tr></table>
</td>
```

I would like to be able to manipulate the address value (a one-line code from saved search) so as to transfer some part of it to a new line. So here is my main question, is it possible to do it and how to do it?

Comment: What if you used the saved search to break apart the individual pieces of the billing address? Rather than a search for the billing address, you could do billing state/billing zip, etc. Might be easier to break apart that way.

Comment: @jdg50 The problem is that I cant break this saved search... i know that its easier but it have to be in one search.

Comment: You dont need another search.  There are result columns for each piece of the adderss, e.g. Bill Zip, Bill State, etc.  Just add those columns to the current search you are using.